# Bootstrap Modal not popping alert when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

Bootstrap Modal button save is not working when clicked.Below is my jquery:

```
$('#add-more-academic').on('click',function(){
        $('#myModal').modal();
    })
    //==================================================
    $('.SaveAcademic').on('click',function(){
        var academic = $('#new-academic').val();
        alert(academic);
```

Upon clicking Save on my modal an alert dialog should display showing what I have entered in my text box. Below is my modal:

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Academic Year</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" name="academic_year" id="new-academic" class="form-control" placeholder="Academic Year">
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success SaveAcademic" id="SaveAcademic">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</html>
```